# Flex 3: looping through repeater items after they've been created... how can i get x, y, width, ect

Tags: apache-flex, repeater, addeventlistener

I have an application that 1) loads an xml, 2) uses a repeater (named projectRP) to create children based on how many "project" tags are in the XML file.  Once a project is created, there are two buttons (created within the child) that moves the project left or right - depending on which of the two buttons is clicked.

After one of the move buttons is clicked, i've created an event listener in the parent application.  I would like to be able to loop through the repeater and find out if two of the projects are overlapping...  if they are, i'd like to move one project below the other.

Is there a simple way i can loop through the repeater items and get all the variables (x, y, width, height) of a specific project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Referencing repeated components section [in official documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=repeater_3.html).